# Gnuplot in Cygwin won't display terminal output ( failed to get the current screen resources qt.qpa.xcb.xcberror: QXcbConnection: XCB error...)

Tags: cygwin, gnuplot

I am running cygwin on a windows 10 and within it gnuplot.

What I want to do is running gnuplot interactively via the qt-terminal.

Since I did this I got this message:

"XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-user'
failed to get the current screen resources
qt.qpa.xcb.xcberror: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 170 (Unknown), sequence: 170, resource id: 90, major code: 146 (Unknown), minor code: 20
Could not connect to existing gnuplot_qt. Starting a new one.
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-user'
failed to get the current screen resources "

I tried setting the environament variable to some path, but this didn't solve anything, since the path of course doesn't contain those juicy screen ressourrces.

The error message then reads:  ``failed to get the current screen resources
qt.qpa.xcb.xcberror: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 170 (Unknown), sequence: 170, resource id: 90, major code: 146 (Unknown), minor code: 20''

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59790350/qstandardpaths-xdg-runtime-dir-not-set-defaulting-to-tmp-runtime-aadithyasb please see answer and discussion there.

Comment: How so? WSL is not cygwin and the "answer" doesn't do anything for me.

Comment: The point is that the error message does not come from gnuplot, but from whatever installed package supports your use of Qt applications. I don't know whether the solution quoted previously exactly fits your installation or not, but you need to look at the runtime environment rather than the specific app that is triggering a failure.

Comment: "I tried setting the environament variable to some path" -- "some path" means, for example, which path did you try to set up? Is the path is user writable and is the permission set to '0700'?

Comment: As stated in my oroginal question, I set the variable to some path. The set path is user writeable.

Comment: have you installed `gnuplot-qt5` package ? Are you running the `XServer` ?

Comment: "I set the variable to some path." -- However, the error message seems to indicate that you are unable to set the XDG_RUNTIME_DIR. Could you confirm that the following gnuplot command return your setting path? `gnuplot> system "echo $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR"` If not so, could you please add to the question how you set up the environmental variable XDG_RUNTIME_DIR?

Comment: @matzeri: I am using Xlaunch to run Xming. Checking the installer it says I have gnuplot-qt5 installed. @binzo The confusion stems from the fact that I decided to post the original error message before I set the path. I tried two things to set it up. I first just set it by `export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=~/` later i created a dedicated path for the same thing to no avail. The error messages are the same then, just without the first sentence.

Comment: Did you set the permission of "dedicated path" to 0700 (**only** the user can read, write and execute) ?

Comment: Yes in deed I did.

Comment: Could you edit your question and add the description of the current status of the problem ?

Comment: You are using Xming as an X server.
Can you use X Window tools other than gnuplot without problems? For example, xterm, xeyes, xclock, xev, etc.