# QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root' when installing Intel oneAPI base toolkit in Ubuntu system

Tags: ubuntu, intel-oneapi

I tried to install the Intel oneAPI toolkit (For using Fortran compiler) in the Ubuntu, by commanding

```
sudo bash l_BaseKit_p_2021.2.0.2883_offline.sh
```

After that, I checked that "Extract l_BaseKit_p_2021.2.0.2883_offline completed!"

and the

`QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'`

error has followed.

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

The issue does not seem to be because of Intel-oneAPI toolkit installation. I could encounter a similar issue with solution in the Stackoverflow forum. Please follow the below link
[QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-aadithyasb'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59790350/qstandardpaths-xdg-runtime-dir-not-set-defaulting-to-tmp-runtime-aadithyasb)

Also, as Intel Fortran compiler is part of oneAPI HPC Toolkit. You need to also install oneAPI HPC Toolkit along with oneAPI Base Toolkit

Hope this solves your issue.

Comment: Please do not answer off-topic questions. SO is for programming questions. Also, Instead of linking to an other question, flag as duplicate